# How to speed up update join query between 2 mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, join, update, query-performance

alright long story short.,
i have **powerful dedicated server**.

```
Intel  I7-6700K -
64GB DDR4 2400 MHz
1x480GB   SSD
```

running mysql server along with nginx,php

```
innodb-ft-min-token-size = 1
innodb-ft-enable-stopword = 0

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 40G
max_connections = 2000

[deploy@ns540545 ~]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G         45G         11G        107M        6.4G         16G
Swap:          2.0G        1.4G        640M
```

it was expensive so i got another dedicated server for cost cutting lets call it 
**not-so powerful dedicated server**

```
Intel  i3-2130  
8GB DDR3 1333 MHz   
2TB
```

running mysql server along with nginx,php

```
innodb-ft-min-token-size = 1
innodb-ft-enable-stopword = 0

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
max_connections = 2000

[root@privateserver deploy]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        7.5G         73M         24M        150M         79M
Swap:           39G        7.8G         32G
```

i moved database from **powerful server** to **not-so powerful server**.

I can feel slight performance degradation while running simple queries which is  fine, but this one query which used to take **2 minutes on powerful server** now it takes around **26.6525 hours and counting on not-so powerful server.**

```
UPDATE content a JOIN peers_data b ON a.hash = b.hash SET a.seeders = b.seeders, a.leechers = b.leechers, a.is_updated = b.is_updated
```

More info about tables which are exactly same on both the dedicated server

```
CREATE TABLE `peers_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `seeders` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `leechers` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_updated` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hash` char(40) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tags` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `category` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `category_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT '',
  `sub_category` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sub_category_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `seeders` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `leechers` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `upload_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uploader` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uploader_level` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comments_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_updated` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `hash` (`hash`),
  KEY `uploader` (`uploader`),
  KEY `sub_category` (`sub_category`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  KEY `title_index` (`title`),
  KEY `category_sub_category` (`category`,`sub_category`),
  KEY `seeders` (`seeders`),
  KEY `uploader_sub_category` (`uploader`,`sub_category`),
  KEY `upload_date` (`upload_date`),
  KEY `uploader_upload_date` (`uploader`,`upload_date`),
  KEY `leechers` (`leechers`),
  KEY `size` (`size`),
  KEY `uploader_seeders` (`uploader`,`seeders`),
  KEY `uploader_size` (`uploader`,`size`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `tags` (`tags`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


mysql> explain UPDATE content a JOIN peers_data b ON a.hash = b.hash SET a.seeders = b.seeders, a.leechers = b.leechers, a.is_updated = b.is_updated ;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | a     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 4236260 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 160     | func |       1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

records in peers_data 6,367,417
records in content 4,236,268

How can i speed up the above update join query ?
i was expecting about 1 hour on not-so powerful server, but 26 hours+ is too much.

what i am doing wrong ? or missing here ?

i have tried to compensate for RAM on not-so powerful server by setting 32 GB + swap space. 
is innodb buffer pool 4 gb too much ?

---

so far i have tried.

1. fixing both charset type same
2. setting innodb buffer pool size to default 128M

and now the task completed in **19.93 Hours**.

---

as per **RolandoMySQLDBA** suggestion,

i am trying **SUGGESTION #2** as those Indexes are required for site to function properly.

i have set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G`

and trying

> SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 50; UPDATE content a JOIN
>   peers_data b ON a.hash = b.hash SET a.seeders = b.seeders, a.leechers
>   = b.leechers, a.is_updated = b.is_updated; SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 25;

It's been **25+ hours** and the query is still running. 
will update when the query finishes.

one more thing is data is not ultra important, its readily available data and i take daily backups., so later ill try suggestion 3 also. and will use whichever is faster.

---

update 2 :

suggestion 2 took 38.36667 hours to complete.

now trying suggestion 3.

Comment: The two `hash` columns have different charsets. is that intentional? And it is the same in both the "powerful" and "not so powerful" server?

Comment: Also the two tables use different engines (MyISAM, InnoDB). is that intentional? And it is the same in both the "powerful" and "not so powerful" server?

Comment: yes, different engines are there to utilize myisam's high speed inserts while different charsets is not intentional, but its same on both servers.

Comment: data gets loaded in peers_data tables from php file in bulk. and it then gets updated in content table.

Comment: "What am I missing?" As I commented above, you are joining two columns with different charset. Try making both the same. I would suppose a "hash" column not to need utf8 so you could use ascii.

Comment: tried that already, set both to ascii_general_ci , and ran the query. it took 19 hours.

Comment: What did you change exactly? Did you change the **charset** of the column (`peers_data.hash`) to `ascii`?

Comment: yes, i set charset of peers_data.hash to ascii_general_ci .

Comment: That's a collation, not a charset. It should be `charset ascii`, to match the column in the other table. Both columns should have `CHARSET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci`

Comment: Related to your question, read this part of Rick James' blog: [Using a Staging Table for Efficient MySQL Data Warehouse Ingestion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table). Lots of useful information there.

Comment: `hash` char(40) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  here is detailed updated https://pastebin.com/WPDFu3px

Comment: In order to test,convert your update statement to select statement using same join and condition.compare how much rows it return and how much it should return.if return rows are more than fix the query accordingly.May be your query was not optimize in powerful server.I have no idea if your current server is really very poor without comparing to previous one.

Answer (score 2):

#YOUR QUERY

Your query should be taking a long time. Why ??? Look at your query:

```
UPDATE content a JOIN peers_data b ON a.hash = b.hash
SET a.seeders = b.seeders, a.leechers = b.leechers, a.is_updated = b.is_updated;
```

Please note the columns begin updated by the query in the `content` table:

- `seeders`
- `leechers`
- `is_updated`

Which of these columns are indexed ?

- `seeders`
- `leechers`

What indexes do you have in the `content` table involving those columns ?

```
KEY `seeders` (`seeders`), <<<<-------------------------------- THIS ONE !!!
KEY `uploader_sub_category` (`uploader`,`sub_category`),
KEY `upload_date` (`upload_date`),
KEY `uploader_upload_date` (`uploader`,`upload_date`),
KEY `leechers` (`leechers`), <<<<------------------------------ THIS ONE !!!
KEY `size` (`size`),
KEY `uploader_seeders` (`uploader`,`seeders`), <<<<------------ THIS ONE !!!
```

What is going on under the hood ?

If you are changing the values for `seeders` and `leeches`, these three(3) indexes are having their leaf nodes reshuffled.

Even if the the majority of the values are not being changed, rows are being locked and copies of your data are being stockpiled in your undo logs (for the sake of MVCC). This results is additional disk I/O (ibdata1 should be growing)

#INNODB

The InnoDB Buffer Pool will be going through the ["Perfect Storm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_storm). Why ?

Please note the InnoDB Architecture (Picture from Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: InnoDB Plumbing]

Please note the `Insert Buffer`. [Here is what the MySQL Documentation says about it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-insert-buffering.html):

> The change buffer is a special data structure that caches changes to
> secondary index pages when affected pages are not in the buffer pool.
> The buffered changes, which may result from INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
> operations (DML), are merged later when the pages are loaded into the
> buffer pool by other read operations.
>
> Unlike clustered indexes, secondary indexes are usually nonunique, and
> inserts into secondary indexes happen in a relatively random order.
> Similarly, deletes and updates may affect secondary index pages that
> are not adjacently located in an index tree. Merging cached changes at
> a later time, when affected pages are read into the buffer pool by
> other operations, avoids substantial random access I/O that would be
> required to read-in secondary index pages from disk.
>
> Periodically, the purge operation that runs when the system is mostly
> idle, or during a slow shutdown, writes the updated index pages to
> disk. The purge operation can write disk blocks for a series of index
> values more efficiently than if each value were written to disk
> immediately.
>
> Change buffer merging may take several hours when there are numerous
> secondary indexes to update and many affected rows. During this time,
> disk I/O is increased, which can cause a significant slowdown for
> disk-bound queries. Change buffer merging may also continue to occur
> after a transaction is committed. In fact, change buffer merging may
> continue to occur after a server shutdown and restart (see Section
> 14.21.2, “Forcing InnoDB Recovery” for more information).
>
> In memory, the change buffer occupies part of the InnoDB buffer pool.
> On disk, the change buffer is part of the system tablespace, so that
> index changes remain buffered across database restarts.

Here is where the ["Perfect Storm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_storm) comes in: By default, InnoDB storage engine reserves up to 25% of the Buffer Pool for Change Buffering. All changes to your three(3) secondary indexes has to pile up in the InnoDB Bufffer Pool's Insert Buffer. When the actual index pages land in the Buffer Pool, the merge process will subsequently be pushed to disk (Note the Insert Buffer inside ibdata1), producing more disk I/O.

#SUGGESTIONS

###SUGGESTION #1

Get rid of those indexes. Why ? This will eliminate the change buffering needed for managing those indexes during your mass UPDATE.

Run the following query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) rowcount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT seeders) seeders_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT leechers) leechers_count
FROM content;
```

If `seeders_count` is less than 5% of `rowcount`, then the cardinality of `seeders_count` can disqualify the `seeders` from being of any use. Same going with `leechers`.

For that index `uploader_seeders`, run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) uploader_seeders_count FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT uploader,seeders FROM content) A;
```

If `uploader_seeders_count` is less than 5% of `rowcount` (from previous query), then get rid of `uploader_seeders` index.

To get rid of those indexes, run this:

```
ALTER TABLE content DROP INDEX uploader_seeders,DROP INDEX seeders,DROP INDEX leechers;
```

###SUGGESTION #2

Change the [Insert Buffer size to the max value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_change_buffer_max_size), the run the query:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 50;
UPDATE content a JOIN peers_data b ON a.hash = b.hash
SET a.seeders = b.seeders, a.leechers = b.leechers, a.is_updated = b.is_updated;
SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 25;
```

Also, set the Buffer Pool Size ([innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)) to `20G`. Change that value in `my.cnf`.

If you have MySQL 5.7, simply run

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 20;
```

If you have MySQL 5.6 and prior, you must restart mysqld.

###SUGGESTION #3 (RISKY)

If you do not want to drop the indexes, you could disable change buffering during the mass UPDATE, then enable it afterwards:

Run the following:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffering = 'none';
UPDATE content a JOIN peers_data b ON a.hash = b.hash
SET a.seeders = b.seeders, a.leechers = b.leechers, a.is_updated = b.is_updated;
FLUSH TABLES;
SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffering = 'all';
```

This is risky because this speeds up changes to indexes in favor of not having buffering to recover in the event of a crash or reboot.

###SUGGESTION #4 (RISKY)

Another cavalier approach would be to [disable the Double Write Buffer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite). Since a restart is required, do this:

- `service mysql restart --skip-innodb_doublewrite`
- Do your mass `UPDATE`
- `service mysql restart`

This is not recommended for Production. Dev and Staging only please !!!

Comment: Should the CREATE TABLE definitions for content and peers_data for the hash column be identical?  With what we can see they are not.  I like your suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: regarding suggestion 2 , i dont have 20 gb RAM, should i still set  (innodb_buffer_pool_size) to 20G ?

Comment: Hey @AMB, I am sorry. The less powerful server should have 5GB innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Comment: Thanks, i am not worried about data loss, its readily available data, and i take daily backups. so i am trying risky but fast solutions , and timinig them, will choose the faster one . Thanks

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  thank you for catching that. That's what happens when you cut and paste as a shortcut to typing and forget to add missing things.

Comment: One thing I notice is that system is already aggressively swapping, IMO higher the buffer pool higher the query execution time due to heavy io in this case. What you say? I've already posted this as an answer but not sure if that's only affecting the query execution time.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash char(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

The hash is hex, correct?  Don't make it utf8mb4; use ascii.

Pack the hash into `BINARY(20)` using `UNHEX()`.  Now it is only 20 bytes.

Hashes of any kind are very "random"  What is probably happening -- the hash cannot be cached, so you are hitting the disk for many, maybe most, rows.  This means disk I/O instead of simply CPU.

Even your faster machine will eventually slow down drastically when the table gets too big (relative to the buffer_pool_size).

Hashes, UUIDs, etc have this drawback.  Try to avoid them.

If `seeders` is just a flag, use `TINYINT` (1 bytes), instead of `INT` (4 bytes).

Why do you have both of these?

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
```

Do other things to shrink the disk footprint of the tables.  Smaller -> more cacheable -> less I/O -> faster.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the updated above use to take couple of minutes,

- how many rows were updated in that time?
- have the number of records in the tables been increased?
- was the cache completely full ?

Also that query seems very agresive, I would suggest to create a file with all the updates in it and later using the percona pt-fifo-split to exexute the file something like:

> mysql -e "select concat('UPDATE content a SET a.seeders =
>   ',b.seeders,', a.leechers = ', b.leechers,', a.is_updated = ',
>   b.is_updated ,' where a.hash=', b.hash) from  peers_data b " >
>   /tmp/updating_seeders.sql

(Please double check the syntax).

This process wont take 2 minutes, more likely couple of hours adding a 1 sec sleep every 500 updates to reduce hight load/lag, plus the time to create the above file:

> (4236268(total records)/500(records per second))/60(minutes)/60 (hours)

Comment: update takes couple of minutes on powerful server.,  from 3mil to 4 mil records gets updated on each run, yes number of records keeps increasing every 5 minutes in content table., how can i check whether cache is completely full ?

Comment: A query like this one will ttell you how you full your cache is: "SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT(DataPages*100.0/TotalPages,2),' %') BufferPoolDataPercentage FROM
(SELECT variable_value DataPages FROM information_schema.global_statusWHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data') A,
(SELECT variable_value TotalPages FROM information_schema.global_statusWHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total') B;" Remember that after reboot you need to warm up your database.

Comment: BufferPoolDataPercentage
100.00 %

Comment: If you add to your my.cnf these two lines, warming will be automatic.
In [mysqld] add
A) innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=ON # to prepare for Warming  B} innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON # to Warm pool

Comment: @AMB Please consider posting 
current complete my.cnf/ini, php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
so we can see how you achieve this volume.
And we will be able to see how SSD influenced your VARIABLES for 
things like innodb_io_capacity & _max, innodb_page_cleaners & innodb_io_read/write_threads.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Server 1**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G         45G         11G        107M        6.4G         16G
Swap:          2.0G        1.4G <--    640M
```

---

**Server 2**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        7.5G         73M         24M        150M         79M
Swap:           39G        7.8G <--     32G
```

---

> i have tried to compensate for RAM on not-so powerful server by setting 32 GB + swap space

Swap should not be a compensate for not-enough RAM. Yes, it's used when there is not enough RAM available, but only to prevent program crash (respect to cloud servers). You could see that the OS aggressively swaps in Server 2.

In development machine, it's ok to compensate with swap. But for dedicated servers, swapping causes all programs in OS to slow down (causing web application slowdown) even though it's triggered by one application. I could assume the main bottleneck here is IO (aggressive swap + mysql IO). Try increasing the server RAM to 16GB with `swappiness` set to 1.

---

> so far i have tried.
>
> 1. fixing both charset type same
> 2. setting innodb buffer pool size to default 128M

Even after reducing buffer pool from 4G to 128M, your system still needs 4G (7.8G - 3.8G) RAM memory for swap to no-swap. Always keep in mind that application servers should not swap at all except to prevent program crash. Also provide whether your 2TB disk is SSD or HDD.

Comment: 2TB disk is HDD

Comment: @AMB you should increase RAM to 16GB (with swappiness set to 1) and check the update query time. Also provide `free -h` after you upgrade RAM

Answer (score 0):

is_updated column definitions are different.  They need to be identical.

Repost your create tables by ADDING it with a date so we can see where you are.

Please post complete results of 
A) SHOW INDEX FROM seeders;
B) SHOW INDEX FROM leechers;
when you have an opportunity.